# Qt - add batch file to qt resource and run it with QProcess

Tags: c++, qt, batch-file, qprocess, qresource

I add a batch file to qt resource and I would like to run it with QProcess. I wrote my code like below, but the batch file doesn't run. What should I do? 
In addition when I replace absolute path instead of resource path, my code executes normal.

```
QProcess myProcess;
myProcess.start("cmd.exe", QStringList() << "/c" << ":/BatchFiles/addServerIP.bat");
myProcess.waitForFinished(1000);
qDebug() << myProcess.readAllStandardOutput();
myProcess.terminate();
```

Comment: Are you sure your batch file's path is correct? doesn't look like it

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yes, because when I get it a absolute path, it executes well with no problem.

Comment: yeah, so, what relative path were actually trying to refer to? Relative paths don't start with `:/`

Comment: That won't work because cmd.exe doesn't support Qt resources(and also wouldn't know about the context of your binary). You need to copy the bat file to a temp file.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Thanks for your comment and suggestion.